# How to Append Sheet 1 to output in Sheet 2 in Google Sheets from JSON imported data

Tags: javascript, json, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to a second in Google Sheets using the below script. It seems like it should be a pretty strait forward request but I am receiving only (ljava.lang.Object...) as my output. I think it has something to do with me using ImportJSON() as the output for sheet 1. I have been messing around with this for a while.

```
function saveData() {
  var sheetinput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = sheetinput.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetoutput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = sheetoutput.getSheets()[1];
  var rows = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  sheet2.appendRow([rows]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You use `appendRow()` so I assume you want to paste the data after the last row with content and starting from column `A`.

Also it is not a good practice to define two variables with the same value. Namely, it is redundant to have both `sheetinput` and `sheetoutput`.

**Solution:**

```
function saveData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1];
  var rows = sheet1.getRange("A1:G"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I want to copy all data from my importjson() in sheet 1 and put it into sheet 2. My intention is to eventually create a trigger so that way I can store the api data from sheet 1 even after it refreshes for historical purposes in sheet 2. Also, not sure why I am getting the same error as in mshcruz's response "Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells. (line 6, file". It is ~3000 rows and columns A:G so shouldn't ever be that many cells.

Comment: the error you are getting is self explanatory. Your spreadsheet file in **total** exceeds the amount of 5 million cells of data and therefore you can't add more data. You can't have more than 5 million data of cells. It is a hard limit by google. @JonK create a brand new file and keep the necessary sheet that you want to copy.

Comment: I understand the error but like I said, there is only around 3000 rows which is nowhere near 5 million.

Comment: @JonK how many sheets do you have and how many cells do you think you have for **all sheets in total**? (in the same workbook/spreadsheet). The hard limit is not per sheet (worksheet) but per spreadsheet (workbook).

Comment: That is everything. Sheet 2 is blank @marios

Comment: share a copy of your file (make the url public). I can't reproduce your error. @JonK

Comment: If sheet1 has a non-empty cell in a very remote part of the sheet (input by mistake maybe), then getDataRange() returns a lot of blank cells that are in the middle of the sheet. You might want to check the range with something like `Logger.log(sheet1.getDataRange().getA1Notation());`.

Comment: @mshcruz don't think that's the issue. But if the OP does not share a spreadsheet everything we discuss here is just speculation. Btw I changed the range to be from A to G . This is just to make sure you are getting only the columns you need.

Comment: @mshcruz  I was going to put in a placeholder url for the json because I cannot share the json to the public. In doing so, the placeholder json worked...so it must be something to do with that. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, I changed your script to A1:G10 thinking this would specify the rows and no longer get an error trying to place 5 million but it still gave me the error. I don't know a lot about all of this so I appreciate your patience but it seems like telling it specific columns/rows would force it to not search and find 5 million. Also, if you have an email, I can send the file. marios @mshcruz

Comment: I had a follow on question to this issue but created a new question here- @mshcruz "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186204/google-sheets-my-json-api-changes-column-order-need-to-always-append-correct" The columns do not come out in the same order every time, which is normal for JSON APIs but I just need the second sheet to append them in the same order so when I dedupe... it captures everything.

Comment: @Marios I can only call out 1 person per comment, so wanted to mention you too. I accepted your answer for this question but do have a follow-on question which I provided the stackoverflow link in the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

[appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) receives only a single row in the form of an array, but you're passing an array of `Object[][]`, which is the output of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). You can copy all the values in that range directly using the [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) method instead:

```
function saveData() {
  var sheetinput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = sheetinput.getSheets()[0];
  //var sheetoutput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is redundant with the variable sheetinput. Both sheets are in the same spreadsheet, so you can use the same variable for the spreadsheet. I'd suggest changing its name as well to something like 'spreadsheet' instead of 'sheetinput'
  var sheet2 = sheetinput.getSheets()[1];
  //var rows = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  //sheet2.appendRow(rows); 
  var sheet1range = sheet1.getDataRange();
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, sheet1range.getNumRows(), sheet1range.getNumColumns()).setValues(sheet1range.getValues());
}
```

Edit: I've realized you wanted to append, not just copy, so I edited the last line.

Comment: Not sure why but this response provided the following error - "Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells. (line 9, file" @mshcruz

Comment: How many rows and columns do you have in the first sheet?

Comment: It is an import JSON so it fluctuates but typically ~3000 rows and columns A:G